# Vertically Sorting in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have what was once an excel file that now needs to be sorted. Everything is separated by tabs, and it is about 3000 lines. I would like it to be sorted by Row and then by Box if the rows are equal. The data looks like:

```
Row Box Description
17  3   C. trach clone
14  6   OMP A E Coli
1   6   R 19 15
2   5   11 Black Ring
1   1   L. Pneumo
```

And I would like it to read

```
Row Box Description
1   1   L. Pneumo
1   6   R 19 15
2   5   11 Black Ring
14  6   OMP A E Coli
17  3   C. trach clone
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What code do you currently have?

Comment: Ordinary `sort` ought to do it. Do you have any question in particular?

Comment: How would I use sort to work on this? I thought sort was only used in lists

Comment: There's a good starting point! How to get your file into a list? Perhaps the [csv](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv) module will be helpful to you, or even just ordinary `str.split`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kevin pointed out, ordinary `sort` does the trick:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

#here you should actually use the csv module for parsing your data
#make sure that there are actually tabs between the columns
a = '''Row Box Description
17\t3\tC. trach clone
14\t6\tOMP A E Coli
1\t6\tR 19 15
2\t5\t11 Black Ring
1\t1\tL. Pneumo'''
data = [x.split('\t') for x in a.split('\n')[1:]]

data = sorted(data, key = lambda x: (int(x[0]), int(x[1])))
print('\n'.join('\t'.join(row) for row in data))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! If I may ask, how would this translate over into Python 2.7 as opposed to 3.2?

Comment: It works fine in 2.7. The problem is that when you copy the code from this page, the tabs are converted to spaces. I fixed it by replacing them with \t in the example. It should now run when you copy-pasta it.